# How to print the carry over columns of ui-grid on the next page using pdfmake

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid, pdfmake

I am trying to print an angular ui-grid with 30 columns and it cuts off at 15 columns. How can I print the remaining 15 columns on the next page.

This is how I am generating a pdf.

```
gridApi.exporter.pdfExport(uiGridExporterConstants.VISIBLE, uiGridExporterConstants.VISIBLE);
```

And these are the config options that i am using

```
exporterPdfOrientation: 'landscape',
   exporterPdfPageSize: 'LETTER'
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: can you post some more code.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest work-around is to try a different page size:
https://github.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/blob/master/src/standardPageSizes.js

Maybe try A2 or even A1.

When printing in Adobe Acrobat Reader, select 'Poster' in the 'Page Sizing & Handling' options.
[image: adobe print menu]